# How to get the actors with more than one movie on the neo4j Movie Graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm playing with the Movie Graph from Neo4J to learn more about Cypher.
I want to get the actors that entered in more than one movie.
How can I create such query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a performant way to get actors that acted in multiple movies (using a cheap degreeness check):

```
MATCH (a:Person)
WHERE SIZE((a)-[:ACTED_IN]->()) > 1
RETURN a
```